# AppleScript editor to connect and disconnect again to specific server

Tags: network, applescript, osx-server

I's trying to write an AppleScript to disconnect and connect again to specific server:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        mount volume "smb://serveraddress/sharename" as user name "username" with password "password"
    end tell
```

But it is connecting only. I'm trying to do both: to disconnect and then to connect again.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using for the disconnect part as well?

Answer (score 1):

I finaly figered out how to do that so i write this code and it works

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        eject alias "Volume name"
    end try
    mount volume "afp://Server/volume"
        open alias "Volume name"
end tell
```

I hope it will be helpful.